# How can i transpile arrow functions in vue files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-5, vue-loader

I have a Vue application which should work in a ES5 Browser (iOS 9).

Some of the functions in Vue components are transformed to Arrow functions: `()=>` which breaks iOS9 Safari. And i don't really understand why some are transformed correctly and some not.

Example:

This is a part from a vue component:

```
    data() {
        return {
            birthday: '',
            accepted: false,
            acceptedForSelectedKids: false
        };
    },
    computed: {
        dataPrivacyLink() {
            return settings.data_privacy_link;
        },
        isOverFifTeen() {
            if (this.privacyToEdit && this.privacyToEdit.owner.age) {
                return this.privacyToEdit.owner.age > 15;
            }
            if (this.birthday) {
                return differenceInCalendarYears(new Date(), new Date(this.birthday)) > 15;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The `data` and the `dataPrivacyLink` functions are transpiled to arrow functions, but not the `isOverFifTeen` function.

Here is how it looks transpiled:

```
data:()=>({birthday:"",accepted:!1,acceptedForSelectedKids:!1}),computed:{dataPrivacyLink:()=>settings.data_privacy_link,isOverFifTeen(){return this.privacyToEdit&&this.privacyToEdit.owner.age?this.privacyToEdit.owner.age>15:!!this.birthday&&function(e,t){Object(c.a)(2,arguments);var o=Object(a.a)(e),n=Object(a.a)(t);return o.getFullYear()-n.getFullYear()}(new Date,new Date(this.birthday))>15}
```

This is how webpack is configured:

```
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/i,
                    loader: 'vue-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loaders: ['babel-loader'],
                    exclude: [/node_modules/]
                },
```

And this is the `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
    env: {
        test: {
            presets: [['@babel/preset-env']]
        }
    }
};
```

In package.json i configured which browsers to use:

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 0.5%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "ios_saf >= 9",
    "not dead"
  ]
```

How can i stop these arrow functions?

Comment: That's an interesting question... I am wondering if using `this` in your function causing this issue. Can you please remove all `this` references and give it another try?

Comment: I only use this in `isOverFifTeen`. But thats the only function i described that transpiles correctly. i changed its implementation to `return false;` and now it also is transpiled to a arrow function. So your guess was right. But my problem still is there. So it seems that all functions containing `this` are not transpiled to arrrow functions.

Comment: maybe this will help https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist

Comment: @A.L i am already using the browserlist. I added it in my initial post

Comment: I suppose this is not a transpiling but inlining simple functions into arrow ones. From this point of view isOverFifTeen looks rather complex and th's why is not inlined into an arrow function. Do you wish to transpile arrow functions into usual functions or vice versa?

Comment: i wish to transpile arrow functions into usual functions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack 5, you need to specify the features that you want to transpile in the `ouput.environment` configuration, as explained here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment.

```
output: {
  // ... other configs
  environment: {
    arrowFunction: false,
    bigIntLiteral: false,
    const: false,
    destructuring: false,
    dynamicImport: false,
    forOf: false,
    module: false,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the plugin in babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions' // add this
    ],
    env: {
        test: {
            presets: [['@babel/preset-env']]
        }
    }
}
```